# jquery: How do I toggle password for 1 input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have my HTML below in 2 different areas of our app to toggle classes `.icon-eye-open` & `.icon-eye-close` for 2 different input fields.

The issue is when the user clicks on the `.icon-eye-close` button both input fields get reveled to show passwords when I only need one input field to get revealed.

Side note: The input fields are generated in python.

What's the best way to execute this?

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="show-password-toggle icon-eye-close icon-align-confirm"></button>
```

JS:

```
$('.show-password-toggle').each(function () {
    var eye = $(this);
    eye.on('click', function() {
        eye.toggleClass("icon-eye-open icon-eye-close");
        eye.siblings("input").each(function () {
            if (eye.hasClass('icon-eye-open')) {
                $(this).attr('type', 'text');
            }
            else if (eye.hasClass('icon-eye-close')) {
                $(this).attr('type', 'password');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Generated python code:
`<input type="text" name="password2" minlength="6" placeholder="Confirm password" id="id_password2">` 
and 
`<input type="text" name="password2" minlength="6" placeholder="Confirm password" id="id_password2">`

Thanks

Comment: We're going to need to see the HTML structure to be able to help you. `eye.siblings("input")` is likely the culprit, but we can't know for sure until we see the HTML. Can you paste the relevant HTML that python is generating?

Comment: Can you show your generated html?

Comment: @mhodges @Ibrahim Khan sure.. the only thing I see that python generates is `<input type="text" name="password2" minlength="6" placeholder="Confirm password" id="id_password2">` and `<input type="text" name="password1" minlength="6" placeholder="Confirm password" id="id_password1">`

Comment: Whole block with `input` & `button` @spidey677

Comment: @IbrahimKhan just posted the whole python generated code. The HTML code is the same just in 2 different places. Just a side note: '.icon-eye-open' and '.icon-eye-open' are font awesome css icons. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `each` to iterate the matched inputs, so yes, you're doing it for both.

You could simply split them up, so there is they are no longer siblings. For example:

```
<div>
  <button type="button" class="show-password-toggle icon-eye-close icon-align-confirm">aaa</button>
  <input type="text" value="bbb">
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="show-password-toggle icon-eye-close icon-align-confirm">bbb</button>
  <input type="text" value="bbb">
</div>
```

Alternatively, use a more specific selector, like `id`.

```js
/*
This is the exact same JS used by the OP
*/

$('.show-password-toggle').each(function () {
    var eye = $(this);
    eye.on('click', function() {
        eye.toggleClass("icon-eye-open icon-eye-close");
        eye.siblings("input").each(function () {
            if (eye.hasClass('icon-eye-open')) {
                $(this).attr('type', 'text');
            }
            else if (eye.hasClass('icon-eye-close')) {
                $(this).attr('type', 'password');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="show-password-toggle icon-eye-close icon-align-confirm">Toggle first</button>
  <input type="password" value="bbb">
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="show-password-toggle icon-eye-close icon-align-confirm">Toggle second</button>
  <input type="password" value="bbb">
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!